# Вопрос о React и Django

Tags: django, reactjs

Всем привет, я создал для реализации определенной функции на сайте внутри Реакт-проекта отдельное Реакт-приложение. Вопрос: я распределил css- и jsx-файлы, как мне теперь подключить их к html-странице? Все мои html находятся в templates в Джанго. Мне нужно сделать `npm run build` и потом указать в html путь к этой папке или не делать `npm run build`, а сразу написать пути к файлам jsx и css, которые касаются только этой функции? Заранее спасибо за помощь.